# Selecionar registro mais recente e nulos a partir da data

Tags: mysql, sql, join

Eu tenho uma tabela 'usuarios' e uma tabela chamada 'pedido', preciso trazer os pedidos mais recentes de cada usuário e caso o usuário não tenha nenhum pedido, retornar essa informação também.

**Tabela 'usuarios'**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Tabela 'pedido'**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Entao, oq preciso é retornar os pedidos mais recentes de cada usuário, ou seja, preciso basicamente que fique assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O mais perto que cheguei, foi usando um UNION ALL pra retornar os usuários que não fizeram nenhum pedido, ficando o sql assim:

```
SELECT 
  u.usuario_id, 
  u.nome_usuario, 
  pe.pedido_id, 
  pe.data_pedido, 
  pe.dados_pedido 
FROM 
  usuarios u 
  JOIN pedido pe ON pe.usuario_id = u.usuario_id 
  JOIN (
    SELECT 
      usuario_id, 
      MAX(pedido_id) as pedido_id 
    FROM 
      pedido 
    GROUP BY 
      usuario_id
  ) pm ON pm.usuario_id = u.usuario_id 
  AND pe.pedido_id = pm.pedido_id 
GROUP BY 
  u.usuario_id, 
  u.nome_usuario 
UNION ALL 
SELECT 
  u.usuario_id, 
  u.nome_usuario, 
  NULL, 
  NULL, 
  NULL, 
FROM 
  usuario 
  LEFT JOIN pedido pe ON pe.usuario_id = u.usuario_id 
WHERE 
  pe.pedido_id IS NULL
```

A minha dúvida é, se esse é o jeito mais correto de ser feito/performático? Já que contém muita informação na tabela e tenho uma vaga sensação que há um jeito melhor de ser feito sem utilizar o UNION.

Comment: @Danizavtz eu dei uma olhada e como eu precisava do mais recente, ao invés de usar o MIN, acabei usando o MAX e acabou retornando nada

Answer (score 0):

Como deseja uma informação agregada de duas tabelas, uma maneira de escrever essa consulta é utilizando o left join. Mas porquê o left join? O Left join é um tipo de junção em que desejamos selecionar todos os elementos da tabela à esquerda que satisfazem a condição do join (cláusula ON) na tabela à direita incluindo elementos que não possuem correspondência na tabela à direita. Desta forma todos os elementos que não possuem correspondência na tabela à direita retornam valores nulos. [Fonte](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)).

No caso concreto a tabela à esquerda é a tabela `usuarios` (pois é a tabela que está declarada à esquerda do comando `left join`)

A tabela à direita do comando left join é `pedido`

Segue um exemplo de como poderia ser implementado:

```
SELECT pe.pedido_id, u.usuario_id, u.nome_usuario,  pe.data_pedido, pe.dados_pedido  
FROM usuarios u LEFT JOIN pedido pe ON u.usuario_id = pe.usuario_id 
WHERE pe.data_pedido = (
    SELECT MAX(data_pedido)
    FROM pedido
    WHERE pe.usuario_id = usuario_id
) OR pe.data_pedido IS NULL;
```